# Python Quick Sort implementation misses out duplicate elements

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, quicksort

I am implementing Quick Sort in Python. My code succeeds in sorting the list, but fails to include the duplicate elements. Please help me find the bug.

```
from random import choice

def quickSort(lst):
    if not lst:
        return []
    else:
        pivot = choice(lst)
        lesser = quickSort([l for l in lst if l < pivot])
        greater = quickSort([l for l in lst if l > pivot])
        #print lesser, pivot, greater
        return lesser + [pivot] + greater

print quickSort([3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 7, 2, 4,234, 234, 23, 1234, 24, 132])
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 23, 24, 132, 234, 1234]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of your conditions needs to be `<=` or `>=` (but not both).

Otherwise, you wind up eventually picking one of the repeated elements as a pivot, and since the other copies are neither greater than nor less than the pivot, they don't get passed to either of the `lesser` or `greater` sorts.

However, since you aren't using unique identifiers for your items, in the example you're using with integers, this will also involve your pivot being included in the set. In order to avoid that, you'd probably need to choose an *index* for your pivot instead of a *value*.

For instance:

```
from random import randint

def quickSort(lst):
    if not lst:
        return []
    else:
        pivot = randint(0, len(lst) - 1)
        pivot_value = lst[pivot]
        lesser = quickSort([l for i,l in enumerate(lst)
                           if l <= pivot_value and i != pivot])
        greater = quickSort([l for l in lst if l > pivot_value])
        return lesser + [pivot_value] + greater
```

---

Tested:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>>
>>> def quickSort(lst):
...     if not lst:
...         return []
...     else:
...         pivot = randint(0, len(lst) - 1)
...         pivot_value = lst[pivot]
...         lesser = quickSort([l for i,l in enumerate(lst)
...                            if l <= pivot_value and i != pivot])
...         greater = quickSort([l for l in lst if l > pivot_value])
...         return lesser + [pivot_value] + greater
...
>>> print quickSort([3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 7, 2, 4,234, 234, 23, 1234, 24, 132])
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 23, 24, 132, 234, 234, 1234]
```

Comment: @ArunprasathShankar See the content I just added.

Comment: I was just about to comment about how your answer would include the pivot twice.  Your edit looks like it'll fix that.

Comment: quick fix -- `greater` should have `l > pivot_value` in the list comp (I believe)

Answer (score 0):

You can't make sure the there is only one element in the list which is equal pivot.
You should return this:

```
return lesser + [pivot]*(len(lst) - len(lesser)- len(greater)) + greater
```

Comment: Note that this will only work properly for basic immutable types - if you tried to do this with more complex types (e.g. a list of lists), you'd get very unexpected results.